# Linked List getValue(int n) should be O(n / 2)

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, doubly-linked-list

The standard Linked List implementation is doubly linked. Therefore we have a headNode and a tailNode respectively. I have read that getValue(int n), as in return the data portion held in the list at the nth element. Now assuming that we do a sequential search on the Linked List starting at headNode the worst case would be O(n) if the position was the last element in the list. However, if we check to see if n > size / 2 then we know whether or not to start the traversal at headNode or at tailNode. This means it would perform O(n / 2), which can be rewritten as O(1/2n).

According to the rules of Big O Notation coefficients do not matter, and therefore the worst case is still O(n). I see a flaw in this logic because if we have a list that contains a large number of nodes, say 1 million, then worst case at 500, 000 is much better than worst case at 1, 000, 000. The worst case would be if the position we are searching for is in fact size / 2. I have implemented this code and found that when the position passed through is less than size / 2 they perform at the same speed, however, when position passed is greater than size / 2, it performs significantly faster. My question is how can we say that this is O(n) when such a simple solution will cut the worst case in half. Clearly coefficients matter, and I cannot see how we can draw the conclusion they are irrelevant. Here is the code:

```
//This is headed by firstNode and tailed by lastNode
public Node getValue(int position)
{
    if (!isEmpty() && position <= size)
    {

        if (position > (size / 2))
            return traverseReverse(position);
        else
            return sequentialSearch(position);

    }

    return null;
}

private Node traverseReverse(int searchIndex)
{
    Node currentNode = lastNode;
    int position = size;
    while (currentNode != null)
    {
        if (position == searchIndex)
            return currentNode;

        position--;
        currentNode = currentNode.previous;
    }

    return null;
}

private Node sequentialSearch(int position)
{
    Node currentNode = firstNode;
    int n = 0;

    while (currentNode != null)
    {
        if (n == position)
            return currentNode;

        n++;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about generic concepts in computer science and not programming. Consider asking this question on [Computer Science.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Complexity does not equal performance. It describes the asymptotic behavior of an algorithm, meaning how it will behave as N increases, which is clearly linear here.

Comment: Anyway keep in mind that O notation is use to speak of *asymptotic* complexities. This means you should consider only *big* `n`. Take `n = 10^50`, it would take billions of years to search an element in such list. Take `n = 10^50/2`, it still takes billion of years to search the element, and nothing really changed from a practical point of view. However take bisection search in a `10^50` element vector, now it takes about `50 * log2(10)` operations to find the element, which is *instantaneous*. *That*'s what big-oh wants to deal with.

Comment: Yeah, question smells like a misunderstanding. For very large n, the execution times grow proportional to N. O(n) is very close to O(n/2) compared to O(n*n) for example. This is true for O(n/2) compared to O(n*n/2), too. Since we are looking at the way the runtime scales up depending on N, the constant factor indeed is small enough that you can ignore it for large n WHEN COMPARING such terms.

Comment: Think of big O complexity as a summary. There are too many constant factors to keep track of, and they don't tell us anything about how runtime *grows* as a function of the input. CPU clock speed is a constant factor. The relative costs of pointer dereferencing vs arithmetic is a constant factor. All sorts of tiny microoptimizations are constant factors. Big O notation specifically ignores all that to focus on the big picture.

Comment: Another way to look at Big O is that you can make all the performance improvements you want to a O(N) algorithm, but as long as the resulting algorithm is still O(N), it'll still be slower that any O(log N) algorithm for sufficiently high values of N. That is pretty much the practical purpose of big O in algorithms.

Comment: Also, tracking constant factors forces us to introduce a scale. 500000 vs 1000000 - 500000 what? Microseconds? Pointer dereferences? Loop iterations? If you keep track of constant factors, you need to be very careful what scale you're measuring things on, and you can't easily compare numbers from different analyses.

Answer (score 3):

Complexity and runtime are related concepts but not identical. Complexity shows the relationship between `n` and the runtime, as `n` increases.

A linear relationship is O(n) regardless of the coefficient. If you want to compare worst case runtimes, by all means do so, but complexity analysis is not the right tool. It's only a starting point.

Whether you search a linked list from the front or the back, the average number of items you'll need to look at is proportional to its size.